# RxJS "dot" vs "pipe" abstraction

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs-pipeable-operators

RsJs moved from a "dot" to a "pipe" abstraction for its operators for [these four reasons](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#why). Would those reasons have also been addressed if the operators were aliased with symbols? So instead of adding a property named `'myOp'` to the prototype, what if the name were a symbol like `Symbol('myOp')`? Then it could be invoked as

```js
var MyOp = require('my-op');
var o = getObservable();
var x = o[MyOp]();
```

Taking the justifications one-by-one:

> Any library that imports a patch operator will augment the Observable.prototype for all consumers of that library, creating blind dependencies. If the library removes their usage, they unknowingly break everyone else. With pipeables, you have to import the operators you need into each file you use them in.

The symbol would only be attached to the prototype when the module is loaded via `require('myOp')` and wouldn't collide because it's a symbol and wouldn't be removed.

> Operators patched directly onto the prototype are not "tree-shakeable" by tools like rollup or webpack. Pipeable operators will be as they are just functions pulled in from modules directly.

Symbols added to the prototype would not need to be shaken because they're imported one-by-one as needed; If the symbol is present on the prototype then it's being used by whoever imported it.

> Unused operators that are being imported in apps cannot be detected reliably by any sort of build tooling or lint rule. That means that you might import scan, but stop using it, and it's still being added to your output bundle. With pipeable operators, if you're not using it, a lint rule can pick it up for you.

Symbols that are loaded but not used are easy to detect; If `var MyOp = require('my-op')` and `MyOp` is not used, then the linter could ask that the package be removed and so the op would never be attached as the module is never loaded.

> Functional composition is awesome. Building your own custom operators becomes much, much easier, and now they work and look just like all other operators from rxjs. You don't need to extend Observable or override lift anymore.

The module `my-op` would declare the operator like so:

```js
var MyOp = Symbol('MyOp');
Observable.prototype[MyOp] = function() { ... }
module.exports = MyOp
```

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. Anyway, I would not want to write `source[Map](x => x + 1)[Filter](x => x % 2);` Also, the `pipe` approach will work nicely with the [pipeline proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator) - if it's incorporated into the language.

Comment: Fair enough! I just figured the `Symbol` way wouldn't require the `pipe` method but if JS is adding a whole new operator to replace the `pipe` method then that's great.

Comment: Tho if symbols were used then we wouldn't need the `|>` operator either. Everyone loves syntactic sugar, but a new operator is seems a high price to pay for a fluent syntax that we could have today using symbols, no? So I was wondering if there were other obstacles that would preclude a symbol approach or is it just that the bracket syntax simply too jarring? To answer my own question again, one issue I could see is that the tooling support for symbols is not great. But then I'd think fixing tooling would be simpler than adding a new operator...

Comment: To plays Devil's Advocate again, while the symbol approach can be done today, it does requires the data traversing the pipe be passed in the `this` argument where as with the `|>` operator it is passed as a proper argument. This has an effect for primitives like numbers (I think) which would be boxed if passed via `this` but not if passed as a propert argument. While I'm not sure that'd affect RxJs which is piping Observable objects, it would affect examples like the [linked example](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator#functions-with-multiple-arguments) that passes numbers.

Comment: The symbol approach also has the disadvantage of being problematic with [ASI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion).

Comment: Hm, do the existing members invoked through, say a symbol on `Symbol` like `iterable`, also suffer from the same problem with ASI? How do those method deal? Or is it something about the chaining that's problematic? Also, and (this might deserve another question but while I'm here...) does the pipe-line proposal allow piping data through methods via the `this` argument? Can I pipe-line using `Array.filter`?

Comment: "Or is it something about the chaining that's problematic?" It's the `[]`. With `return source[Map](x => x + 1)` put a newline between `return source` and `[Map](x => x + 1)` and see what happens.

Comment: Hm, do I need to flip on ASI? [This](https://repl.it/@kingces95/ASI-with-Brackets) seems to work for me.

Comment: Nope. ASI is not optional, but I was wrong. Just tried it out and ASI is not a problem, here.

Comment: The link with reasons is broken, I have been searching for it :) https://rxjs.dev/guide/v6/pipeable-operators

Comment: I have feeling that `pipe` approach is more open and easy for changes, then `symbol` approach. Also there is already great tooling support, actually I wouldn't be happy if library I am using one day become incompatible or even less compatible with my IDE.